# Como obter a quantidade de dias entre duas datas em python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data

Basicamente preciso obter a diferença de dias entre o dia de hoje e uma data que extraio de um csv.
Estou salvando o dia de hoje e a data que puxei do csv em objetos e subtraindo os dois para obter a diferença em um deltatime. Até aí tudo certo, porém não estou conseguindo tirar disso a quantidade de dias dessa diferença.

Se eu tento usar o método .days ele dá esse erro: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

E se antes disso eu tento converter o objeto pra datetime ele dá este erro: TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]

O que eu poderia fazer pra consertar o código e obter a quantidade de dias entre as datas? Abaixo segue o código.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("serv.csv")

for row in df:
    #obter dia de hoje
    d1 = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today())
    #obter data do csv
    d2 = pd.to_datetime(df["PasswordLastSet"], infer_datetime_format=True)
    diff = (d1-d2).days
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar a função abs no final, ele retorna valor numero absoluto.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("serv.csv")

for row in df:
    #obter dia de hoje
    d1 = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today())
    #obter data do csv
    d2 = pd.to_datetime(df["PasswordLastSet"], infer_datetime_format=True)
    diff = **abs(**(d1-d2).days **)**
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado, Denis. Mas esse método me retorna a quantidade dias, horas, segundos, e milésimos por extenso, assim: "60 days 01:15:35.632329". O que eu queria era extrair apenas o "60", ou seja apenas o número de dias e nada mais. Talvez formatando essa string? Sou novo em Python e no site, perdão qualquer erro.